# Is there a way to sort from the taxonomy and title?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to know how to sort the taxonomy and names in ascending order.

I tried to use this piece of code: 
`"orderby" => 'floor, title'`

but can't show the result I want.

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  "post_type" => 'shop',
  "floor" => '',
  "orderby"=>'',
  "order"=>'',
  "pagination" => 'true',
  "query" => '',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'paged' => $paged,
 ), $atts));
 global $wp_query,$paged,$post;
 $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $temp = $wp_query;
 $wp_query= null;
 $wp_query = new WP_Query();
 if(!empty($post_type)){
  $query .= '&post_type='.$post_type;
 }
    if(!empty($floor)){
  $query .= '&floor='.$floor;
 }
    if(!empty($orderby)){
  $query .= '&orderby='.$orderby;
 }
    if(!empty($order)){
  $query .= '&order='.$order;
 }

 if(!empty($query)){
  $query .= "";
 }else{
  $query .= $query;
 }
 $wp_query->query($query);
```

## my short code

```
[loop_food 
posts_per_page="-1"
post_type="shop"
floor="G,F1,F2,F3"
orderby="floor,title"
order="asc"
query=""
]
```

### I expect the output of

```
G
|shop1|shop2|shop3
F1
|shop4|shop5|shop6
F2
|shop7|shop8|shop9
```

### but the actual output is

```
G
|shop2|shop3|shop4
F1
|shop6|shop5|shop1
F2
|shop9|shop7|shop8
```

I tried to do but didn't get the desired result.
Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy